# Refresh function in Oracle - APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX to create a food ordering application. The application allows the user to add an item to their order through a popup window in which the user can select the quantity of the ordered item.
My problem is that after the user adds the item to the order from the popup window the popup window is only closed and the main page is not refreshed. I have a PL/SQL region on the main page that prints the items chosen along with their prices and quantity so that region needs to be automatically refreshed after the popup is closed. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

When saying a "popup window", is that a modal page? If so, how about a **dynamic action** on "Dialog closed"; a TRUE action would then be "Refresh".

Comment: I'm pretty new to apex. What does a modal page mean and how do I create it?

Comment: That's what I asked you - what do you call a "popup window"? How did you create it? As of a modal page: if you look at "Properties" (right hand side of the screen), you'll see the "Appearance" section which has the "Page Mode" property. It can be set to a "modal page". Switch to "Help" mode (question mark icon in the middle section of the Apex page) and read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic action on the parent page on dialogue close of the modal page which refreshes the region.